# Ace Editor and Dojo 1.9 with AMD

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, ace-editor

I'm having trouble including Ace editor with Dojo 1.9 using AMD loading eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'dojo/on',
        'dojo/dom',
        'somelocal/folder/ace'
        'dojo/domReady!'
    ],
            function(
                    on,
                    dom,
                    ace
                    ) {
                var editor = ace.edit("editor");
                editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
                editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/twig");
            });
</script>
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: _define.modules is undefined
var module = _define.modules[moduleName];
```

How can I include Ace as above within dojo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't try loading ACE like that, it will fail all the way long, even if you manage to swizzle require/define at the moment of loading.

what works so far is:

- load ACE via script tag, as shown in examples
- use ace.require for loading ACE extensions/themes instead of the Dojo's require

the why: ACE has been built with the require-js, most modules are also written in CJS instead of AMD; that means you will have trouble also building your Dojo app.

And [here](https://gist.github.com/mc007/46dc749a730a80a2532b) is my ACE editor for Dojo (grab what you need)